# Google Firebase notifications can't subscribe topics

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I have a new firebase app. The purpose is to send notifications to topics from php server to iOS device.

I have successfully tested everything up to the point of sending notifications from server to specific device id.

However, topics refuse to play nice.

From the PHP side:

```
function call_firebase_notification ($signal){ 
    $to = "/topics/demo";
    $title = "php function test real";
    $body = "php function test real body";
    $payload = json_encode(array(
                    "to" => $to ,
                    "notification" => array(
                      "title" => $title,
                      "body" => $body
                    )
                ));
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: key=AIzaSyBr0G...Euxr5x4_0",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: ". strlen($payload)
        );
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
    $return = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}
$return = call_firebase_notification("test");
var_dump($return);
```

I get a most positive result: string(34) "{"message_id":9067338503195970026}"

From iOS side:

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/demo"];
```

My current partner-in-crime also says that got a positive result when subscribing.

However no notifications arrive (to note it out again: notifications successfully delivered when sending to his id) and no topics appear when trying to send notification from firebase console.

EDIT:
(note to self and to the world)

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

never use these unless absolutely necessary or bored out of your head, this was a demo snippet so i didnt really care, but generally you should update your ssl certs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple actually: time.
In my case it was about 2 days, but after that notifications to topics randomly worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try to add **priority** and **content_available** parameters on your notification payload.

```
{
  "to": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification": {
     "title": "test",
     "body": "my message"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true
}
```

I also noticed that there's a service disruption within Firebase Clould Messaging yesterday per [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Cloud%20Messaging/16002).

Comment: Thanks for the answer my dear friend, however they do not seem to work

Comment: While they did not help at that aspect, they ended up quite useful, as without these notifications only work with the app on the front